# Report security vulnerability

Tags: web-application, exploit, vulnerability, bug-bounty

I need to understand how to report a security vulnerability on a web application, given the website owners have no such bug bounty programs.

Brief information on target:
The website is built to support a small business. Their business impact may be limited to a city.

So I want to know:

1. How to initiate a discussion over the existing vulnerability on a positive approach?
2. Is proton mail is good option for conversation, or their is better secured and if possible anonymous platform?
3. Is their a report format that I can use to share details about exact vulnerability and exploit that I built?

Thanks.